# Android-switching navigation burger icon to back icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I already implemented the Navigation Drawer from this tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial

Here the issue is how to change the ActionBar in the Fragment, so when I go to the Fragment it shall show me the back Arrow instead of burger icon on ActionBar and when the Back Arrow icon is clicked, it shall leave the fragment and the ActionBar should back to the first state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle while opening the fragment.When the user clicks back button from the fragment, pop back stack and reset the support action bar indicator as hamburger. You might have to override

> onSupportNavigateUp()

method in your activity if back button not working

```
 @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Good luck.

EDIT

Here is a sample code to implement the behaviour you need.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = getTitle();
        mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        setupToolbar();

        DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[2];

        drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, "Connect");
        drawerItem[1] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, "Fixtures");

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerLayout =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        setupDrawerToggle();
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }

    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new TestFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TestFragment2();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getTag()).commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            showBackButton(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    void setupToolbar(){
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    void setupDrawerToggle(){
        mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        //This is necessary to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle upon state change.
        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()){
                   mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }else{
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public void showBackButton(boolean isBack){
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!isBack);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(isBack);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                fm.popBackStack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            showBackButton(false);
            setTitle(getTitle());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check the `onBackPressed()`, `showBackButton()` and `setupDrawerToggle` methods.

Comment: If you don't mine,please sahre some more information.

Comment: @AnuCute can you tell me what exactly you need clarification with?

Comment: where i have to implement showBackButton() method ?in fragment or main activity?

Comment: @AnuCute You will have to implement the method in your activity and call it after opening your fragment. onSupportNavigateUp will also be in your activity. When the user presses back button, you will have to change the icon back to hamburger via code and enable the drawer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working but there is an issue here while clicking back button of fragment it's redirecting to the fragment drawer list instead of home page how to implement it ?

Comment: @AnuCute I have added a sample code for you to understand the implementation. Hope it is helpful.